# Prove that if a sequence $(x_i)$ does not converge to $a$ in a metric space, there exists neighborhood of $a$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-explanation

> Prove that if a sequence $(x_i)$ does not converge to $a$ in a metric space, there exists neighborhood $A$ of $a$ and $(x_i)\nsubseteq A$.

---

Further down I present my attempt. I appreciate all input/corrections and welcome any intuition about this problem!

---

*Proof*. Since the sequence $(x_i)$ does not converge to $a$, we therefore by definition conclude that it *does not* exists 
 $\varepsilon$ such that $D(x_i,a)<\varepsilon$. In other words, $D(x_i,a)\geq \varepsilon$.

Since the distance between $x_i$ and $a$ is greater or equal to $\varepsilon$, we can construct an open ball $B_{\varepsilon}(a)$ around $a$ with a radius less that $\varepsilon$. Hence,

$B_{\varepsilon}(a)=\left\{x \in M : d_M(x,a)<\varepsilon \right\}$ where $M$ denotes the metric space.

> A subset $U$ of a metric space $(M, d_M)$ is called open if, given any point $x$ in $U$, there exists a real number $\varepsilon > 0$ such that, given any point $y$ in $M$ with $d_M(x, y) < \varepsilon$, $y$ also belongs to $U$. Equivalently, $U$ is open if every point in $U$ has a neighborhood contained in $U$.

According to above, we conclude that there exists a neighborhood $A$ of $a$, since the criterias are met for $B_{\varepsilon}(a)$.

Since all the $x_j$ in $(x_i)$ has a distance $D(x_i,a)\geq \varepsilon$ we can conclude that no $x_j$ can lie within $B_{\varepsilon}$. Thus, any subsequence will also not lie within $B_{\varepsilon}$ and further lying outside the neighborhood $A$ of $a$.

(QED?)

Comment: A possible intuition is that $(x_i)$ converges to $a$ iff given **any** neighbourhood of $A$ of $a$, the sequence eventually winds up in (and stays in) $A$. Therefore, if $(x_i)$ does *not* converge to $a$, it means there must be some neighbourhood $A$ of $a$ such that the sequence is *not* eventually contained in $A$. (This is basically just by taking a logical negation.)

Comment: @nicomezi I have corrected it, about the notation!

Comment: Appreciate your effort. Thank you. (+1)

Comment: Note that saying "the sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $a$" is not the same thing as saying "$a$ is a limit point of the sequence $(x_n)$". For example, $\pm 1$ are both limit points of the sequence with $x_n=(-1)^n$, but the sequence does not converge. Which is meant here?

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is clearly false as stated: if we consider (in the reals) the sequence $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ which converges (only) to $0$, we have that for any $x_n$ from the sequence (e.g. $x=1$, or $x=\frac12$) we cannot have a neighbourhood of that point that misses **all** points of the sequence, because by definition that neighbourhood contains that $x_n$.

Also, if we take an enumeration of the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ as a sequence (which we can do as that set is countable), *all* neighbourhoods of *every* $x \in \mathbb{R}$ contain *infinitely many* points of the sequence, yet the sequence does not converge to any point of $\mathbb{R}$.